# struct and error syntax with erlang

Tags: erlang

I want to know the use of struct and error with erlang

for example I have problem to understand this syntax

```
{error, bad_amount} -> {struct, [{"status", "error"}, {"reason", "badamount"}]};
```

best regard
batista

Answer (score 4):

The `struct` and `error` atoms does not really mean anything in Erlang. It is just atoms, [tags](http://www.erlang.se/doc/programming_rules.shtml#REF32551) that identifies what type of tuple you have. The first tuple is just two atoms. The second is a tuple with the first element being an atom (the tag) and the second being a list of tuples.

Tagging is an Erlang *convention*. It is a common thing to do (so common that [records](http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/records.html) are implemented as tagged tuples). Tagging is the nearest a type system you get in Erlang since you make the values carry type information, and the tags are commonly used for pattern-matching.